# How to call methods dynamically without using eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Nom
          %th Rôle
          %th{ width: "110px" }
      %tbody
        - @organization.users.each do |user|
          %tr
            %td
              %p.font-bold= user.full_name
              %p.font-sm.text-gray-600= user.email
            %td.capitalize= user.role
            %td
              = link_to 'Détails', eval("#{user.role}_path(user)"), class: 'primary'
              %a.danger Enlever de l'organisation
```

But using `eval` is pretty much always a bad idea, whether for performance concerns or for security concerns.

Comment: Try `link_to 'Détails', [user.role, user]` – Rails should be able to construct the path out of the array if everything is set up correctly.

Comment: What do you mean "if everything is set up correctly"? I get this error "undefined method `attendant_user_path'". I guess you are suggesting I did not setup my routes as I should :D

Comment: What about `link_to 'Détails', [user.role, id: user]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `send` or even better `public_send`

```rb
public_send("#{user.role}_path", user)
```

Comment: sweet! thanks! I'll have another question like that one but trickier!

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to it :)